# How to upgrade from one version to latest version in .NET framework?

Tags: .net

I have a project built in .NET framework V4.5.2 and now I want to upgrade my project to V4.7

Can anyone guide me on how to do this?

Comment: You need the reference assemblies so you can compile the app.  That requires the 4.7 developer pack, Google takes you to the download location with its first hit.  Demanding that your users also update to 4.7, well, not such a great idea just yet.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue because I was trying to install a nuget package which requires the 4.6.1 version at least (Mine was 4.5.2), so I right clicked to the project and selected the  properties option and change the Target Framework as shown in the image and that was enough! Keep in mind that you have to install previously the Net. Framework you are trying to upgrade.

[image: Change the framework]

Comment: By the way be aware to upgrade your installed nuget packages as needed.